# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to submit a POST form using a div but I'm getting this MethodNotAllowedHttpException message.

HTML

```
 <form action="{{ url('upload') }}" method="POST" name="form" >
   ...
   <div onClick="document.forms.form.submit();">
     <i class="icon upload"></i>
     {{trans('gui.upload')}}
   </div>
 </form>
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(
[
  'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
  'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
],
function()
{
  Route::post('upload', ['middleware' => 'admin', 'uses'=>'DatabaseController@upload']);
});
```

Error Message

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 7717:

in compiled.php line 7717
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in compiled.php line 7713
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in compiled.php line 7691
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 6965
...
```

It works if I try with Route::any

Comment: What error are you exactly getting?

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 7717

Comment: Check which request is sent by the client (in Network), it can be either it's wrong or it's get transformed into `GET` by the middleware.

Comment: I just checked and it says method POST :/

Comment: It works if I try with Route::any

Comment: What is the URL generated with `url('upload')`?

Comment: The URL generated is http://localhost/guild/public/upload

Answer (score 0):

Three possible reasons this could be happening

1. You have a different route in `routes.php` that also happens to match the `/upload` URL.  Consider using named routes and `routes(...)` instead of `url(...)` to help mitigate this sort of problem
2. You have a middleware that's changing the HTTP verb of the request
3. Your request posts successfully, but automatically redirects to a different URL without a matching HTTP verb in `routes.php`